# Export managed function to unmanaged

Tags: c#

I'm trying to export some of my functions using ( https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports ) but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace Verificare
{

    static class Exports
    {
        [DllExport]
        public static void Salut()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I am using DLL EXPLORER to view the exported functions and unfortunately, in my dll there is no exported function.

Comment: What results or error are you getting, what is the expected result versus the actual result. What have you tried sofar

Comment: Are you building for "x86, ia64 or x64"? The documentation clearly states you cannot export functions when building for AnyCpu.

Comment: I've tried for x86 / x64 and same problem. The expected result? I should be able to see the function exported using the dll explorer which I;m not seeing atm.

Comment: I would avoid this. Loading a specific version (or at all) of the .NET framework into an application should not come as a surprise but should be an informed decision. You can cause problems loading the .net runtime into an application that is not aware of it, or perhaps have loaded a different version of the framework (again, possibly as a sideeffect of loading a dll).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried and verified here, it's working as expected :

- Created a *Class library* project
- Added the package from NuGet
- Changed configuration to x86

Created a few functions :

```
using RGiesecke.DllExport;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public static class Class1
    {
        [DllExport]
        public static int Hello()
        {
            return 1;
        }

        [DllExport]
        public static void Nope()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the functions are exported correctly:

[image]

If in doubt, check the DLL with [CFF Explorer](http://www.ntcore.com/exsuite.php), try on a new project.

**NOTE**: when you create another configuration of your project, the output is not in bin\Debug but in bin\x86\Debug, make sure you are checking the right DLL.

Comment: Problem solved ( I accidentally renamed the class name ( Class1 ) and that was why it wasn't working ) .